# Qgridlayout control the size of the widget

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qgridlayout

I am trying to use Qgridlayout for my GUI. I wish to reduce the width of the Qspin as shown in the picture. Any suggestions how I can do it? thanks

```
    layout.addWidget(checkBoxVBG,1,0)
    layout.addWidget(checkBoxIREF,2,0)


    layout.addWidget(boxVBG, 1, 1)
    layout.addWidget(boxIREF, 2, 1)


    layout.addWidget(checkBoxZERO_X,1,2)
    layout.addWidget(checkBox4MOSC,2,2)


    layout.addWidget(boxZERO_X, 1, 3)
    layout.addWidget(box4MOSC, 2, 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a fixed width and an alignment to the left.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        checkBoxVBG = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("VBG")
        checkBoxIREF = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("IREF")
        boxVBG = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        boxIREF = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        checkBoxZERO_X = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("ZERO X")
        checkBox4MOSC = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("4MOSC")
        boxZERO_X = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        box4MOSC = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()

        for spinbox in (boxVBG, boxIREF, boxZERO_X, box4MOSC):
            spinbox.setFixedWidth(60)

        layout.addWidget(checkBoxVBG, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(checkBoxIREF, 2, 0)

        layout.addWidget(boxVBG, 1, 1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        layout.addWidget(boxIREF, 2, 1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)

        layout.addWidget(checkBoxZERO_X, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(checkBox4MOSC, 2, 2)

        layout.addWidget(boxZERO_X, 1, 3, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        layout.addWidget(box4MOSC, 2, 3, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```